# Problema de compilacion de OpenGL C++ en Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

necesito su ayuda. Tengo un error al compilar mi archivo main.cpp. Estoy trabajando con OpenGL, cmake, glfw y glad. El error es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Codigo:

```
#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main()
{
//Initialization
glfwInit();
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
//glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE); ON 
//MacOSX

//Window creation

int x_wsize = 800;
int y_wsize = 600:

GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(x_wsize, y_wsize, 
"OpenGl_Basics_Engine", NULL, NULL);
if (window == NULL)
{
    std::cout << "Failed to create GLFW window" << std::endl;
    glfwTerminate();
    return -1;
}
glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);


//Glad initialization
if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress))
{
    std::cout << "Failed to initialize GLAD" << std::endl;
    return -1;
}

//rendering window size
glViewport(0, 0, x_wsize, y_wsize);


return 0;
}
```

Adjunto tambien la ruta de creacion del ejecutable y de debug. asi como tambien la de mis directorios:

[image: Depuracion]

[image: General]

[image: Directorios]

Cabe a destacar que no tiene ningun error sintactico y el IDE reconoce perfectammente las librerias (o al menos eso parece).
Si necesitan cualquier otra informacion dejenmelo saber. Desde ya les doy las gracias.